# Modifying a string in Assembly Intel x86

Tags: string, assembly, x86, nasm, intel

I'm programming a **Playfair cipher** in Assembler Intel x86 (For NASM) in Windows. I created a matrix (From "a" to "z" without the "j") in the data section, and I receive the string to cipher with _gets.
While I iterate the received string and cipher its characters, **how can I store them in another string so I can print it**? Or even modify the one that I received? Though that's not the idea.

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?

Comment: I'm using Windows.

Comment: Cool!  Is this 32 bit code?  Generally, you need to allocate some memory (e.g. in the bss segment) and then write the string you want there.  You can write data the same way you read it: with a memory operand.

Comment: 32bit code, yes. I thought about creating a string in .bss, but how can I write the string char by char? I'll be reading the received the string by blocks of two, compare them to the matrix, and then write the ciphered chars in the new string. So I have to use lea to write the string?

Comment: Yeah, you need to write the string char by char.  `lea` won't write to memory, but you can use a `mov` for example.  Just like when you write to any other memory location.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out. Should I have another thing into consideration?

Comment: Not really.  That's about what is there to it.  If you get stuck somewhere, feel free to ask another question.